# Does Voldemort have other options?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, character-motivation

In the battle of Hogwarts, after Voldemort knew that all Horcruxes were destroyed and the curse *Avada Kedavra* will not affect Harry a second time, does Voldemort never think of fleeing the scene and coming again with a better plan instead of going one on one with Harry? *He can create Horcruxes again right?* and then he can think about what went wrong with killing Harry and after that strike hard.

Comment: Evacuate?  In our moment of triumph?  I think you overestimate their chances!

Comment: I don't think he could create any more horcruxes. He had already split his soul into eight pieces - the piece in his resurrected body, six horcruxes and the piece in Harry - and only the piece in his body was left. I don't think he got the other pieces of soul back when the horcuxes were destroyed.

Comment: @Wallnut If he did, he wouldn't be so weak at the end. xD

Comment: @HarryJohnston It took a moment to place that as I had HP on the brain. Go Grandma Tarkin!

Comment: @Wallnut I think he was able to (he could just split the piece in his body, like he did to create every other Horcrux) but he was unwilling - remember, he thought his soul was in 7 pieces, which was a deliberate choice tied to it being "a powerful magical number" or some such thing. Creating more Horcruxes would nullify this effect.

Comment: @Wallnut Voldemort chose six Horcruxes (seven pieces of soul) because seven is a powerfully magical number, but as far as we know there was nothing really preventing him from making more Horcruxes if he absolutely needed (or wanted) to. He might have to commit more murders to split what remained of his soul into more pieces.

Comment: A split soul becomes very unstable, as dumbledore mentioned. It took power of the highest level to split the soul so much. He will severely weaken his remaining soul if he split it further. Maybe he can withstand 1 or 2 more..but more than that..I don't think so.

Comment: What would prevent _Avada Kedavra_ from working on Harry a second time?

Comment: @prakharlondhe "It took power of the highest level to split the soul so much." Do you have anything to support this claim? The only thing that's stated in the book to split your soul is murder, which doesn't really require "power of the highest level". I don't recall any mention of needing to do anything special to keep a soul that's been split multiple times intact, and I'm not sure if the consequences of an "unstable" soul are ever actually addressed.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate even though the other question references the movie, because both questions are still asking the same basic question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## The Dark Lord wouldn’t have fled because he saw no reason to.

After Harry survived the Killing Curse in the Forbidden Forest, the Dark Lord was still confident that he could defeat Harry and win the battle to rule over the wizarding world.

> *“Accidents!’* screamed Voldemort, but still he did not strike, and the watching crowd was frozen as if petrified, and of the hundreds in the Hall, nobody seemed to breathe but they two. ‘Accident and chance and the fact that you crouched and snivelled behind the skirts of greater men and women, and permitted me to kill them for you!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

He didn’t flee because he believed he could win, so believing that, he stayed to fight and win. Even after he considered that he might not be the master of the Elder Wand, he was confident in his skill.

> “But what does it matter?’ he said softly. ‘Even if you are right, Potter, it makes no difference to you and me. You no longer have the phoenix wand: we duel on skill alone … and after I have killed you, I can attend to Draco Malfoy …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

He wouldn’t have considered fleeing, since he thought he could end Harry right then.

Comment: Absolutely! Plus, I guess, he would see that as an insult to his ego if he fled from Harry, given the history of the two.

Comment: @IshitaSinha not to forget, Harry told Voldemort that everyone who fought Voldemort that night, now has a magical protection due to Harry’s sacrifice. Considering that this could be right and acknowledging this by trying to flee in front of those people, implies now having some hundred enemies who do not fear him at all (and possibly are right in not fearing him). That’s surely not an option, not to mention that he won’t get out of Hogwarts under these circumstances. His only chance was to assume that Harry is not right and to prove that in a “now or never” fashion.

Comment: Please remind me: Where was the flaw in Voldemort’s reasoning then? In everything you’ve quoted, Voldemort is … well, objectively right. Did Voldemort simply not know that Harry was the owner of the Elder Wand? (I don’t have the books handy and a cursory search doesn’t turn up a detailed enough summary).

Comment: @KonradRudolph The Dark Lord didn’t know Harry was the master of the Elder Wand, and he also didn’t realize that the reason Harry lived is because he rebuilt his body with Harry’s blood containing Lily’s sacrifice, which tied Harry to life while his body kept the power of Lily’s sacrifice alive.

Comment: @Holger If the Dark Lord believed he would die, it’s likely he’d consider fleeing a better alternative than the possibility to his own death. He believed nothing was worse than death, and feared it above all.

Comment: @Bellatrix well, he *refused* to believe that. The explanation of why he refused to believe that, does not necessarily imply that he was aware himself about these reasons. There’s simply no alternative to believing that he’s shortly before his final triumph for him. As said, acknowledging that Harry is right, would also imply that fleeing would be futile. So fleeing is no option, either way.

Comment: @Holger True, but the reason he didn’t flee is because he thought he would win.

Comment: Sure. No objection. That’s what he thought before and what he continued to think, regardless of what Harry said. His counterarguments (“accident and chance”) might have come out a bit louder than intended, but *of course*, he never considered that Harry could be right. Not even for a second. Of course, he would win…

Comment: The Dark Lord battled like an idiot. Don't get into a wand power contest. Unleash fiendfire.

Comment: @Joshua The Dark Lord definitely should’ve used Fiendfyre! ;)

Comment: As per your answer @Bellatrix It seems voldemort is too proud to flee from scene and I think if he just put his ego aside and flee from the scene he definitly come with a better plan. It is just a speculation that he can imprisoned harry for a lifetime and spread the news that he is died eventually people forgot and in the end its a good plan if he cant kill harry. but as I say It is just a speculation and you are right he thinks that it is just an accident that harry return from death. Alas he can think twice of that event!! :)

Comment: @KDeogharkar Thanks, I’m glad you like my answer! :)

Answer (score 15):

Adding to Bellatrix's answer, it would almost defeat the whole fearing the Dark Lord thing if he is so keen to evacuate when the odds tilt a little off his favour. 
People will get hope to stand against him, and any other plan Voldemort hatches afterwards is guaranteed to be met by even more resistance.

Moreover he has lost too many of his good Death Eaters. The Ministry will probably reform again and now they will be alert as hell.

All in all, it was only possible to attack at that moment only or to be faced by even worse conditions in the future.

Comment: He recreated his evil empire from nothing after its first collapse. He might be able to do the same again.

Comment: But that was mostly because of the element of surprise. Now that everyone knows he is at large and his supporters' identities are known, he may not be that successful in doing it again.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Plus, foiled by HP as an infant, then *retreating* from HP as a student? Who'd follow him in confronting HP again as an adult?

Comment: @DevSolar I'm here for that fanfic...

Answer (score 2):

He had the Elder Wand - and, after murdering Snape, he considered himself to be the Elder Wand's master. So why not stay and fight? The whole point of the Elder Wand is that you don't lose. Especially against someone like Harry Potter, whom Voldemort always considered extraordinarily lucky, rather than extraordinarily great.

Moreover, if at that moment - Elder Wand in hand - The Dark Lord Himself chose to run from Harry, well. Good luck getting any of your followers to respect you after that.